# Disable removing tags used on single questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

This is a request to turn off the automatic removal of tags that only apply to a single question, preventing the situation where questions end up with just a meta tag against them.

I have noticed that over here on Movies and TV that there are a fair few questions that only have a meta tag like for example these:

- [What's with the alien and the video game?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2338/1887)
- [Why is the big year record not accurate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2303/1887)
- [Who is the murderer in the beginning of Tucker & Dale vs Evil?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2249/1887)

Looking at the revision history for these questions, we can see a mysterious edit which claims to have edited tags but in fact has done nothing. [There exists a setting on all Stack Exchange sites](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/dont-expire-single-use-patent-number-tags#comment127_103) which is responsible for expiring tags that only have a single question on them, which in the case of the above questions (and many others) is resulting in leaving questions with a single tag not related to the Movie or TV show the question is about.

Disabling this setting will mean that we'd have to clean up more tags, but I think the benefits will outweigh the harm by useless tags that won't get deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by TylerShads, this was indeed disabled back in around December for this site, amongst others like Science Fiction & Fantasy.

As with all sites that have this disabled, remember that this requires great diligence on the community to stay on top of tags. You have to make sure to watch out for typos, bad tags, and other things that usually fly under the radar.